# Table doesn't exists in Liferay 6

Tags: java, liferay-6

I have defined a data table and associated objects in Liferay 6, but when I run the code it says the table doesn't exists, and it's true. The code runs fine when I create the table by hand just copy-pasting the create table from the model implementation, but I expected the table to be created when deploying.

The user has all the privileges needed to create it.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem. and @urvish is correct you have to change build number in [image]

service properties file.

> **problem**
>
> When multiple developers working on portlet that uses servicebuilder
> will give below exception “Build namespace has build number which is
> newer than “. When developer commits service.properties file and that
> deployed on other developer machine then it will throw below
> exception
>
> ***Best Practice: To avoid these kind of errors, follow these:***
>
> create service-ext.properties file at the same locaiton of service.properties
>
> add build.number={higher-value or same value in exception)
>
> Deploy portlet again
> .

Answer (score 0):

Check values of `build.namespace` in service.properties file and value of

```
select buildNumber from servicecomponent where buildNamespace = <<build.namespace from service.properties>>
```

Now the buildNumber return from query must be lesser than value of `build.number` propert in service.properties. If it is not then just set the value of build.number to 9999.

Sometimes due to mismatch, changes are not applied to database.